# Incorrect display in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

This is my [website](http://flyinfante.ahmetcanguven.com/)

My index.php file is correct in all other browsers except Internet Explorer. I am really confused. I couldnt find the problem. Can someone help me please.

Comment: Be more specific about what your problem is

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What does the problematic code look like?

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 2):

Your website is missing a doctype. Without that it's basically pure luck how it renders in different browser. (Admittedly it still is afterwards, but somewhat less.)

IE is rendering your site in [quirks mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html), that might explain some of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrote about footer then try simply add to your table tag in footer style "float:right;" or your class "fright".